# Secure my html content in android

Tags: android, html, security, webview, zip

I have offline html content includes images, audio, javascript and text file. I want to secure my html file content from user.

**I have followed following steps to secure my data.**

1. Encrypted my html content as zip folder.
2. When I want to show my html conten in webview at that time I have decrypted my html content as unzip folder.
3. When user close the webview I have deleted the unzip files

**Issue:**

When content visible in webview user can able to see the unzip files,
I want to restrict user to don't see/unable to access my unzip content.

I need suggestions on this.

Comment: "I want to secure my html file content from user" -- then don't store it offline on the device.

Comment: It is offline app, So I should store it in offline.

Comment: So you must transform your offline app to an online app ! When the content is decrypted, user can get it. This is his terminal, so he can get the contents.

Comment: Just a thought... Not exported contentprovider with encryption on fly... It maybe, just maybe could work... But if webview do some caching it will not. And no, i dont have any links.

Comment: "It is offline app, So I should store it in offline" -- then do not worry about the users having access to that content. There is little that you can do to stop somebody from getting that content, as it is on their device, and they can have access to all the same tools that you do. So, for example, anyone can defeat your encryption, because your decryption key is part of your app, and anyone who wants to can go grab that key.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion? like SSL handshake server to client. Can we process that a content can be visible only in app browser when CA key matchs. I just given kind of mechanism shall we proceed for offline data?

Answer (score 0):

One method that would, at the least, make it more difficult for the user to access the files while offline, would be to store all of the files in an SQLite database, and use [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) to encrypt said database.

Then you could have the key for the database be derived during runtime. That way, the data would only be decrypted in memory, and it would be much harder for an attacker to access it.